# Matlab VS. C++ in matrix calculation

Tags: c++, matlab

I am using C++ to do some matrix calculations using Armadillo library.

I tried to make it similar to the Matlab version.

But when I run the code.

While Matlab took about 2 - 3 min, C++ took about 20 min.

I searched a bit and realized that some people also asked why C++ is slower than Matlab in matrix calculations.

But I heard that C++ is way faster than Matlab. So I was wondering whether C++ is not as good as Matlab in terms of Matrix calculations in usual.

Below is just part of my entire code.

Is there any way I can speed up C++ matrix calculations?

Should I use a different library?

```
while (dif >= tol && it <= itmax) {
        it = it + 1;
        V = Vnew;

        Vfuture = beta * (Ptrans(0) * Vnew.slice(0) + Ptrans(1) * Vnew.slice(1) + Ptrans(2) * Vnew.slice(2));

        for (int a = 0; a < Na; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < Nd; b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < Ny; c++) {
                    Mat<double> YY(Na, Nd);
                    YY.fill(Y(c));
                    Mat<double> AA(Na, Nd);
                    AA.fill(A(a));
                    Mat<double> DD(Na, Nd);
                    DD.fill(D(b));
                    Mat<double> CC = YY + AA - mg_A_v / R - (mg_D_v - (1 - delta) * DD);
                    Mat<double> Val = 1 / (1 - 1 / sig) * pow(pow(CC, psi) % pow(mg_D_v, 1 - psi), (1 - 1 / sig)) + Vfuture;
                    double max_val = Val.max();
                    uword maxindex_val = Val.index_max();
                    int index_column = maxindex_val / Na; // column
                    int index_row = maxindex_val - index_column * Na; // row
                    Vnew(a, b, c) = max_val;
                    maxposition_a(a, b, c) = index_row;
                    maxposition_d(a, b, c) = index_column;
                }
            }
        }

        // Howard improvement
        for (int h = 0; h < H; h++) {
            Vhoward = Vnew;

            for (int i = 0; i < Na; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < Nd; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < Ny; k++) {

                        temphoward(i, j) = beta * Vhoward(maxposition_a(i, j, k), maxposition_d(i, j, k), 0) * Ptrans(0) + beta * Vhoward(maxposition_a(i, j, k), maxposition_d(i, j, k), 1) * Ptrans(1) + beta * Vhoward(maxposition_a(i, j, k), maxposition_d(i, j, k), 2) * Ptrans(2);
                        Vnew(i, j, k) = temphoward(i, j) + utility(Y(k) + A(i) - A(maxposition_a(i, j, k)) / R - D(maxposition_d(i, j, k)) + (1 - delta) * D(j), D(maxposition_d(i, j, k)), sig, psi);

                    }
                }
            }

        }

        tempdiff = abs(V - Vnew);
        dif = tempdiff.max();

        cout << dif << endl;
        cout << it << endl;

    }
```

And this is the part from the matlab.

```
while  dif >= tol && it <= itmax
tic;
it = it + 1;
V = Vnew;  

vFuture = beta*reshape(V,Na*Nd,Ny)*P;

for i_a = 1:Na                  %Loop over state variable a
    for i_d = 1:Nd                  %Loop over state variable d
        for i_y = 1:Ny                  %Loop over state variable y

            val = reshape(Utility(Y(i_y) + A(i_a) - mg_A_v/R - (mg_D_v - (1-delta)*D(i_d)),mg_D_v),Na*Nd,1) + vFuture;

            [Vnew(i_a,i_d,i_y), indpol(i_a,i_d,i_y)] = max(val);
            
            [indpol_ap(i_a,i_d,i_y),indpol_dp(i_a,i_d,i_y)] = ind2sub([Na,Nd],indpol(i_a,i_d,i_y)); 
            
        end 
    end
end

% Howard improvement step
for h = 1:H
     Vhoward = Vnew;
    for i_a = 1:Na                  %Loop over state variable a
        for i_d = 1:Nd                  %Loop over state variable d
            for i_y = 1:Ny                  %Loop over state variable y

                 Vnew(i_a,i_d,i_y) = Utility(Y(i_y) + A(i_a) - A(indpol_ap(i_a,i_d,i_y))/R - ...
                     (D(indpol_dp(i_a,i_d,i_y)) - (1-delta)*D(i_d)),D(indpol_dp(i_a,i_d,i_y))) ...
                     + beta*reshape(Vhoward(indpol_ap(i_a,i_d,i_y),indpol_dp(i_a,i_d,i_y),:),1,Ny)*P;


            end 
        end
    end
end

dif = max(max(max(abs(V-Vnew))));
disp([it dif toc])
end
```

Comment: With your C++ code, did you compile with optimizations turned on? (sometimes called release mode)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the optimization is. I put #define ARMA_NO_DEBUG in the code. Is this the optimization you are saying or should I do something else?

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Compilers have flags that tell them how much to automatically optimize code and if you don't provide any, then no optimization happens which gives you the slowest code you can have.  If you are using g++ or clang add the `-03` option to turn on full optimizations.

Comment: I am using Visual studio 2019 now. Is there a similar thing in VS also?

Comment: Select a Release build instead of Debug, there should be a drop-down list in the IDE

Comment: Can you post the MATLAB code you are comparing to?

Comment: I choose Release instead of Debug, it used to take 1000 seconds for one loop but now it is 17 seconds for one. May I ask what is different between Release and Debug?

Comment: But still, Matlab takes about 7seconds....

Comment: Release enables compiler optimizations and other settings to make the code more efficient. These can radically affect the final code, [this is an overview of what's possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler). Debug, on the other hand, is meant to make debugging easier, the result is a very simple translation of C++ to assembly.

Comment: Matlab has many person-years of development and refinement. It may not be easy to beat it without a deep understanding of writing fast C++, algorithms, data structures, etc.

Comment: This is not about one language being faster than another, this is about your C++ code being very inefficient and doing work that the MATLAB code doesn’t do. Look again at the code inside the three loops, and figure out what parts you can simplify or move outside the loops. For example creating an array is expensive, you should reuse the same ones over and over again instead of creating new ones.

Comment: @ChangseokMa Following the hints by Cris, move all of your `Mat<double>` declarations to at least the outside of the outermost for loop, or preferably outside of the while loop.